# React-Redirect to external link with react-router-dom or <a> Tag

Tags: react-native, react-router-dom

I am building a react blog app, I am using a functional component where I will be using some internal and external links both. For the internal links I am using `Link` from `react-router-dom`which is working fine but for the external link I am not able to decide will an `Link` from `react-router-dom` works, which directs to the path of the external URL or an `<a>` tag should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using `react-router-dom` is to navigate to application routes by making changes in the DOM and not reloading the whole page. This scenario is applicable to internal links.

When coming towards external links. It is something that is not the part of our application. We cannot render it our application context. So, a solution to that is using an `a` tag for external links.

Answer (score 0):

`Link` is basically a wrapper of an  tag with a lot of upside functionalities like,

- A  can know when the route it links to is active and
  automatically apply an activeClassName and/or activeStyle when given
  either prop.
- The  will be active if the current route is either the linked
  route or any descendant of the linked route.
- To have the link be active only on the exact linked route, use
   instead or set the onlyActiveOnIndex prop.

Read the rest at https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

You can use the anchor tag if you plain something plain. use Link for ease of use.